# How do I change the size of an array in Perl6 after creation?

Tags: arrays, raku, rakudo

In perl6 I can create an array of fixed size as so:
my @array[5];

How can I then change the size of the array later on to be larger, for instance I want array to be of size 7 now

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the shape of an already existing shaped array.

---

To do something like this you can bind the positional variable to a new array.

```perl6
my @array[5];
@array := my @[7];
```

I don't think there is a test for switching out a declared shape array in the spec tests ( nor do I think there should be )

---

A probably safer way is to declare the array without a shape and immediately bind it to an array with the starting shape;

```perl6
my @array := my @[5];
@array := my @[7];
```

The reason I say this is safer, is a compiler *might* do some optimizations that assume it will always have the declared shape.

```perl6
@array[*-1] => @array[4]

@array[6] => Failure.new(…) # ( or even a compile-time error )
```

Comment: I am still new to perl6 coming from a Java background i can do int x[]; and then later in another line I can do x= new int[5];  I was wondering if the same was possible here.

Comment: @AphroditeVenus Why don't you just use the normal arrays? In Java (I assume) you have to do that because of limitations in the design, Perl (5&6) try to remove as many limitations as possible. The reason Perl 6 even exists is because there were limitations in Perl 5 that couldn't be worked around easily.

Comment: wouldn't forcing the size of the array cause faster compilation? Also I need its constraint checks

Comment: @AphroditeVenus Forcing the size slows down compilation, and possibly even slows down the runtime. I think it even has to create a new class just for arrays of a given shape. The native shaped arrays can sometimes be faster, but they are generally only used in code that needs to be very heavily optimized.

Comment: Eventually, shaped native arrays *will* become faster than ushaped arrays.  At the moment however, there's still a lot of boxing to HLL / unboxing from HLL constructs going on that need to be optimized away.  A great part of the design of Perl 6 is to allow optimizers to have the necessary introspection to be able to do this.  It's just that no one has had the tuits to write those optimizers (although quite a lot of optimizing is going all already: compare your code running with and without --optimize=off :-).

Comment: putting an Array that has a shape into a variable that doesn't have a shape as part of its declaration will work with binding just like @BradGilbert suggests in this answer. It will then enforce bounds checks for you, but the variable will still allow you to bind a new array with a different shape later on. This will not give you trouble with future optimizations, either.

Comment: @BradGilbert so enforcing the type generally slows down compilation speeds even for scalar variables?

Comment: @AphroditeVenus It really depends, there is still a lot of optimization work to be done. Currently if you add type annotations it could slow it down because it has to check the types. In some cases it speeds it up though. I wouldn't worry about it though, just add ypes where it makes sense.